# Spring Roo and Hibernate: how to prevent deletion

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I am using Spring Roo as framework and Hibernate as persistence.

In my application users and roles have a many to many relation. This is how the `User` model is defined:

public class User {

```
/**
 */
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Rol> roles = new HashSet<Rol>();
```

};

There is no navigability from `Role` to `User`.

When a user is deleted, here's the hibernate query that's produced:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_5_0_, user0_.password as password2_5_0_, user0_.email as email3_5_0_, user0_.enabled as enabled4_5_0_, user0_.login as login5_5_0_, user0_.name as name6_5_0_, user0_.first_last_name as first7_5_0_, user0_.segundo_last_name as segundo8_5_0_, user0_.version as version9_5_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user as user1_5_1_, roles0_.roles as roles2_6_1_, rol1_.id as id1_4_0_, rol1_.name as name2_4_0_, rol1_.version as version3_4_0_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join role rol1_ on roles0_.roles=rol1_.id where roles0_.user=?
Hibernate: delete from user_roles where user=?
Hibernate: delete from role where id=? and version=?
```

I am getting an exception, and I believe the cause is the last line. Why is it deleting the role? How can I prevent that?

Comment: Cascadetype all is responsible

Comment: how should I set its value then?

Comment: The many to many record will be deleted even without cascase and it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply lose the `(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`.

By specifying `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` (which includes by definition `CascadeType.REMOVE`) on the `roles` relation you basically tell hiberate you want the `roles` to be deleted when a `user` is deleted, which is unnecessary.

All you want is that the row from `user_roles` (the relation row) will be removed when user is deleted, and this is done automatically by hibernate without specifying "CascadeType.REMOVE / ALL"

Comment: awesome, this was of great use. Now I understand what `cascade` is for. I also have some entities that when deleted I'd want to also delete other relationed entities. i.e my entity `Person` has many to one `Job`s but there is no navigability from job to person. Is there any way I could use cascade so when a `Job` is deleted all the people entries with that job would also be deleted? Or the only way of doing this is manually?

Comment: This question has more than one possible answer so I suggest you search/post it